# Questionable NTP Traffic at Firewall?

Tags: networking, firewall, malware, ntp

I checked my firewall logs and noticed odd traffic patterns for NTP or UDP/123 (shown below). I don't understand the round robin'ing that's occurring from my hosts. And I don't understand why its happening on multiple hosts.

When I configure time, I usually use Apple default, Microsoft default, Fedora default, Ubuntu default, etc. *If* I configure, then I use NIST's servers.

First question: is anyone familiar with the behavior shown below? Perhaps it is a common library sampling in an effort to find the closest NTP server with the lowest latency?

Second question: does m0n0wall allow me to rewrite traffic such that I can redirect all NTP requests to `time-c.nist.gov` and `time-d.nist.gov`? I don't want to drop the traffic outright; but sending it to a known good host would make me feel better.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those look like pool.ntp.org servers. These are the default servers for Fedora and Ubuntu. They have a [vendor namespaces program](http://www.pool.ntp.org/vendors.html) so Fedora uses `0.fedora.pool.ntp.org` and Ubuntu uses `0.fedora.pool.ntp.org`. In order for servers to be listed in the pool they have to serve accurate time. So there really is no need to change the settings and it helps take the load off the NIST servers.

Comment: Thanks @dfc. It looks like a couple of machines are set to particiape in the [Open NTP Pool Project](http://www.pool.ntp.org/en/). Related: how does one differentiate "good" UDP/123 from "bad" UDP/123? All the jumping around appears to masks malware egressing data over UDP/123.